# i can't add the menu icons to the tool bar in visual studio xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-toolbar

it seems that what ever i did i cant set the icons visible to the tool bar, i've tried to do researches on many platforms, but nothing helped.

here is the xml menu:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/event_ic"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_event"
    android:title="profile"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/details_menu"
    android:title="details"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

you can see that even if i set the android:showAsAction to always, i still get the event item in the pop up menu without the icon.